# SQL - Multiple one-to-many relationships

Tags: sql, entity-framework, relationship

Is it possible somehow to do multiple one-to-many relationships between 2 tables?
Like:

Table abc

- abcID
- defID
- message

Table def

- defID
- abcID
- message

If yes how can I then make a new abc entry with the entity framework?

Comment: How would this schema represent multiple one-to-many relationships?

Comment: [abc] abcID -> [def]abcID ||||| [def] defID -> [abc]defID

Comment: @Will A: I think the OP is after a many-to-many relationship - one record from `abc` can relate to many `def` records, and vice versa.

Comment: @user407674 - weird - could you explain the relationship you're after in a bit more detail, please?  @OMG - not sure - that'd be straightforward - this is starting to look odd.  :)

Comment: If you take a look at www.expweb.dk/model.jpg you will see that the question table relates to the answer table and the answer table relates to the question table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need a single Many-Many relationship. Simply move QuestionId out of the quiz_answers table and move AnswerId out of the quiz_questions table:

```
Create Table quiz_questions
(
QuestionId ... Not Null Primary Key
, Question ...
, ...
)

Create Table quiz_answers
(
AnswerId ... Not Null Primary Key
, Answer ...
, ...
)

Create Table quiz_question_answers
(
QuestionId ... Not Null References quiz_questions ( QuestionId )
, AnswerId ... Not Null References quiz_answers ( AnswerId )
, Constraint PK_quiz_question_answers Primary Key ( QuestionId, AnswerId )
)
```

Comment: How do I know that AnswerId 7 belongs to QuestionId 2 then?

Comment: @user407674 - Because you will have a row in the quiz_question_answers table mapping QuestionId 2 to AnswerId 7. You may be seeking two Many-Many relationships: one to map *available* answers to question and another to map *actual* answers which would entail another vector which is the person making choosing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a one-to-one join from abc to def and then another from def back to abc; so abc joins to def on defID and def joins to abc on abcID.